# There are no message read on the pyCharm for discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The discord bot is running on the PyCharm. User enters hello on the discord, but on the PyCharm it does not show the message content.

The following coding on the PyCharm are shown below

```
import discord
import random

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

TOKEN = 'Discord Token Key'


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.channel.name == 'general':
        if user_message.lower() == 'hello':
            await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}!')
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == 'bye':
            await message.channel.send(f'See you later {username}!')
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == '!random':
            response = f'This is your random number: {random.randrange(1000000)}'
            await message.channel.send(response)
            return

    if user_message.lower() == '!anywhere':
        await message.channel.send('This can be used anywhere!')
        return


client.run(TOKEN)
```

I need to implement

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

If not then it will get this error TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

The code is successfully operating and the chatbot is ready to roll.
[Chatbot online in PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L7kH.png)

But then moment user input something on the discord, the PyCharm does not read anything. Chatbot online at Discord [Chatbot on Discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvABm.png). Input from User at Discord [User Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3cxN.png). Pycharm does not read any input from the user [No reading at Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huzy5.png).

Version:
PyCharm: 2022.1.4, Python: 3.9.10, Discord: 2.0.0, Discord.py: 2.0.1

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `discord.Intents.default()` does not include message_content intent which is needed to read messages. [[source](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intent#discord.Intents.default)]

Changing your `client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())` to the code below should work.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I found out another solution to solve this issue which is writing this code as below

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```